# Received a warm welcome letter along with job contract. How to respond?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, new-job, human-resources, first-job

I received my job contract by post and also a warm welcoming letter. I have to send back the signed contract by post. Just want to know should I also include a warm thank you note? Is it professional? Or send back the contract only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, you don't need to send a warm cover letter, but a brief cover letter is fine.

The letter of offer will be a form letter from HR. You only need to send back the signed contract and leave it at that.

*However*, if you want to you can add a short cover letter stating you have accepted the contract and you are looking forward to commencing your new position.  But that's entirely up to you :)

Comment: I'd settle fir "great! Thanks! looking forward to it!" ... unless there are questions you still need answers to, in which case this is a good time to ask them.